# Sonar Api - Access to database

Tags: database, api, widget, sonarqube

I am writting a widget for Sonar. It has to upload a string and put it in the sonar database. (Table "properties", "prop_key" = "views.def", It change the structure of views for the plugin porfolio manager).

I coded a little form where the user can copy/paste the string. It appears on my sonar web UI. But I don't know what to do now...

I need to put that string into the sonar DB. How can I communicate with the DB from a widget (with API tools) ?

I searched in Sonar API documentation, but I am a bit overflowed by the informations, and it is not everytime clearly explained.

Thanks for the time you will spend on my question.

EDIT : I found how to access to the database table "properties", by the org.sonar.api.config.Settings class. (method setProperty to write, getString to read (a String :p)).

But this methods havn't access to the DB for writting, so the modifications made by setters are not saved :/